# Read a local WSDL file with XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, wsdl

I'm trying to get WSDLImporter to work with a local WSDL-file and have some problems. A remote file is no problems as I use the MetaDataExchangeClient like this:

```
    private MetadataSet GetRemoteMetaData(string wsdlUrl)
    {
        var address = new Uri(wsdlUrl);
        var mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
        var metadataExchangeClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(address, mexMode);
        metadataExchangeClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
        ICredentials networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        metadataExchangeClient.HttpCredentials = networkCredential;
        return metadataExchangeClient.GetMetadata();
    }
```

But for local files I try to use the XmlReader like this:

```
    private MetadataSet GetLocalMetaData(string wsdlPath)
    {
        return MetadataSet.ReadFrom(XmlReader.Create(wsdlPath));
    }
```

and get this exception:

```
<definitions xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'> was not expected.
```

So it seems like it can't handle the namespace/prefix. I know XmlReader also can take a XmlReaderSettings class so I played around with it a bit but couldn't find anything that worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the XML returned at `wsdlPath` look like?  It's especting a `wsx:Metadata` element with various `wsx:MetadataSection` elements beneath, I don't think any `definitions` elements should be there.

Comment: Oh I see, then I'm way off in my thinking here. Guess I have to find a way to transform the WSDL XML first before I read it to to a MetadataSet. The wsdlPath is a path to a just a regular soap wsdl xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MetadataSet GetRemoteMetadata(string wsdlFilePath)
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(wsdlFilePath);
    var reader = xmlDoc.CreateReader();
    var serviceDescription = System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription.Read(reader);
    var metadataDocuments = new MetadataSection[] {
        MetadataSection.CreateFromServiceDescription(serviceDescription)
    };
    return new MetadataSet(metadataDocuments);
}
```